# How should I enable the Precise Answer feature in the Azure QnAMaker model?

Tags: azure, azure-cognitive-services, azure-qna-maker

Currently, I am working on a chatbot project that answers based on a knowledge base that is uploaded as a PDF to the QnAMaker service.
However, I have learnt that Azure uses a Deep Learning feature to extract the short answers from the long answer passages that are ranked through the Search Cognitive Service.

May I please know how I could enable this feature.

**Reference documentation:** https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/qnamaker/reference-precise-answering

**Result (with Span enabled):**

[image]

**Result (with Span disabled):**

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can enable [precise answers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/qnamaker/reference-precise-answering) when using the Text Analytics resource with Custom question answering feature. The answerSpanRequest parameter has to be updated for the same.

```
{
    "question": "How long it takes to charge surface pro 4?",
    "top": 3,
    "answerSpanRequest": {
        "enable": true,
        "topAnswersWithSpan": 1
    }
}
```

Similarly, the users can choose to disable precise answers by not setting the answerSpanRequest parameter.

```
{
    "question": "How long it takes to charge surface pro 4?",
    "top": 3
}
```